# Aligning pictures along the center line

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment

I create a picture like this. How can I align them along their middle lines?

My code was like this:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%some codes to drat the first picture.
\end{tikzpicture} 
\quad $\xrightarrow{\text{stabilization}}$ \quad
\begin{tikzpicture}
%some codes to drat the second picture.
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

The picture was like this:

[image]

But I would like the first one and the arrow goes up a bit such that they are aligned with the middle line of the third one in vertical direction.

Comment: Please make your code fragment compilable (a complete small document)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see if the following solve your problem:

```
\begin{center}
\tikzset{every picture/.append style={baseline=(current bounding box.center)}} % <---
\begin{tikzpicture}
%some codes to drat the first picture.
\end{tikzpicture} 
\quad $\xrightarrow{\text{stabilization}}$ \quad
\begin{tikzpicture}
%some codes to drat the second picture.
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend puting all in 1 tikzpicture, and use scope.
[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[->] (-1,0)--(1,0) node[midway,above]{stabilization};

\begin{scope}[xshift=-2.5cm]
\fill (0,0) circle(3pt) node[above=1mm]{$p_i$}
(.5,0) circle(1.5pt) 
(-.5,0) circle(1.5pt) 
(-1,0) circle(1.5pt);
\draw (-1.5,0)--(1,0);
\end{scope} 

\begin{scope}[xshift=3cm]
\fill (45:.5) circle(1.5pt) node[right=1mm]{$p_i$}
+(45:.5) circle(1.5pt) node[right=1mm]{$p_{n+1}$}
(.5,0) circle(1.5pt) 
(-.5,0) circle(1.5pt) 
(-1,0) circle(1.5pt);
\draw (-1.5,0)--(1,0) (-135:.7)--(45:1.5);
\end{scope} 

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two of the standard options are either to use `\vcenter{\hbox{...}}` to vertically center or to set the `baseline` appropriately. The first option requires you that you set everything in the same math group.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
$\vcenter{\hbox{\begin{tikzpicture}[bullet/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=#1}]
\draw (-1,0) -- (1,0) node[pos=0.2,bullet=1pt]{}
node[pos=0.4,bullet=1pt]{} node[pos=0.6,bullet=2pt]{} node[pos=0.8,bullet=1pt]{};
\end{tikzpicture}}}\quad
\xrightarrow{\text{stabilization}}\quad
\vcenter{\hbox{\begin{tikzpicture}[bullet/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=#1}]
\draw (-1,0) -- (1,0) node[pos=0.2,bullet=1pt]{}
node[pos=0.4,bullet=1pt]{}  node[pos=0.8,bullet=1pt]{};
\draw (0,-0.25) -- (1,0.75) node[pos=0.6,bullet=1pt,label=right:$p_i$]{}
node[pos=0.8,bullet=1pt,label=right:$p_{n+1}$]{};
\end{tikzpicture}}}$


$\vcenter{\hbox{\begin{tikzpicture}[bullet/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=#1}]
\draw (-1,0) -- (1,0) node[pos=0.2,bullet=1pt]{}
node[pos=0.4,bullet=1pt]{} node[pos=0.6,bullet=2pt]{} node[pos=0.8,bullet=1pt]{};
\end{tikzpicture}}}\quad
\xrightarrow{\text{stabilization}}\quad
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-0.1cm,bullet/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=#1}]
\draw (-1,0) -- (1,0) node[pos=0.2,bullet=1pt]{}
node[pos=0.4,bullet=1pt]{}  node[pos=0.8,bullet=1pt]{};
\draw (0,-0.25) -- (1,0.75) node[pos=0.6,bullet=1pt,label=right:$p_i$]{}
node[pos=0.8,bullet=1pt,label=right:$p_{n+1}$]{};
\end{tikzpicture}$

\end{document}
```

[image]